# Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in... SessionManager.php on line 492

Tags: magento2, session

now I have an error in Magento 2 that shows this error:

There has been an error processing your request

> Warning: Cannot use a scalar value as an array in
> /home/web/domains/web.com/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php
> on line 492

Do you know how to solve this? I use Magento 2.3.5

Answer (score 3):

Its a bug just change the line 492 with this

do you see this line

**Replace this**

```
protected function _getHosts()
    {
        return $_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY] ?? [];
    }
```

**with this**

```
protected function _getHosts()
    {
        
       return isset($_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY]) ? [$_SESSION[self::HOST_KEY]] : [];

    }
```

Comment: Hello, I have this in my 492, I replace with your code?

        $hosts[$host] = true;


Thanks

Comment: check updated ans

Comment: Thanks! I have edited :)

Comment: is it working ?

Comment: I don't know as I cleared cookies before from the internet browser and was ok, for now I don't see the error

Comment: please accept the ans if it works for you

Comment: Actually it is line 506 which must be changed (in Magento 2.3.4).

Comment: i was using 2.3.5 p2 so i had ans it based on that.. but obviously he can check fot the fucntion between thanks